# Highcharts Timeline xAxis

Tags: charts, highcharts

I've been round and round with this one and I can't seem to drop on an answer.

I've essentially done all I need except for the XAxis as the bottom - This is a timeline chart and I can't get it to render dates at all. (for each point of data for the delivered line, I have a sql datatime entry).

I have tried the various options, UTC, converting to millieseconds etc. but to no avail. Can anyone tell me how I can advance this?

My goal is to have a chart that can display in minutes (up to 2 hours worth = 160 points across) and to automatically scale to hours and days if need be - if poss).

My current setup is as follows :

(asp.net / vb.net / SQL) - although I am happy to receive c# help and I will convert)

Markup :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
         Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: { useUTC: true } });

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: { type: 'spline' },
                title: { text: 'Delivered vs CTR' },
                subtitle: {text: 'Source: Campaign Name'},

                xAxis: [{
                    type:'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 20,
                    dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                    hour: '%H:%M<br>%p',
                    minute: '%l%M<br>%p',
                    second: '%H:%M:%S'
                }                    

                }],
                yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis

                max: 20,
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value;
                        },
                        style: {
                            color: '#DE4527'
                        }
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'Clicked',
                        style: {
                            color: '#DE4527'
                        }
                    },
                    opposite: true

                }, { // Secondary yAxis
                                  lineWidth: 1,  
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Delivered',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value ;
                        },
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    }


                }],
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 4,
                            lineColor: '#666666',
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 120,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Delivered',

                    data:  <%= DeliveredChartData%>,

                    color: '#4572A7',
                     lineWidth: 1, 
                    yAxis: 1,
                    marker: { radius: 2, symbol:'circle'}
               }, {

                    name: 'Clicked',
                    color: '#DE4527',
                    marker: { radius: 2},
                    data:  <%= ClickedChartData%>,

                }]
            });
        });


</script>
```

Code behind :

```
       Dim dt As DataTable = dsAreaChart.Tables(0)

    Dim _dataDelivered As New List(Of Integer)()
    Dim _dataClicked As New List(Of Integer)()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Dim tmil As DateTime = CDate(row("campTableTimeStamp"))

        'need to somehow add campTableTimeStamp as XAxis timeline

        _dataDelivered.Add(CInt(row("campQtyDelivered")))
        _dataClicked.Add(CInt(row("campQtyClicked")))

    Next
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()

    DeliveredChartData = jss.Serialize(_dataDelivered)
    ClickedChartData = jss.Serialize(_dataClicked)
```

As you can see I have the campTableTimeStamp field in sql already to go - but how to pass it in with the other.

Can anyone advise ?

Many thanks for any assistance.

Peter

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier to answer with a fiddle, or with an example of the data that results from your function.

One thing you will need to do: remove the 'tickInterval:20' - this is telling the chart to add a label every 20 milliseconds.

Next, make sure your data is structured properly.

should look like `data:[[timestamp, numeric value],[timestamp,numerica value],[timestamp,numerica value]...]`

or, if your timestamps are at regular intervals, you can set the pointStart and pointInterval properties, and skip providing the timestamp values in the data array, so you would have only `data:[y value, yvalue, yvalue...]`

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval

If that doesn't help, please clarify, and add data output sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I really appreciate you taking the time. I will continue to revise and adopt suggestions.